# Error running *requests*

Tags: python, macos, python-requests, osx-yosemite

Installed Python/Pip on OSX 10.10 using instructions here http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/starting/install/osx/

Only installed to gain access to Pip

Installed requests using `pip install requests`

Ran script

```
import requests

feed_url = 'http://www.mylocation.com/the_data'

#grab xml from URL
r = requests.get(feed_url)
r.text

print r
```

Error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_all_listings.py", line 1, in <module>
    import requests
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/utils.py", line 12, in <module>
    import cgi
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/cgi.py", line 50, in <module>
    import mimetools
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/mimetools.py", line 6, in <module>
    import tempfile
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 32, in <module>
    import io as _io
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyErr_ReplaceException
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
```

Output from **otool -L $(which python)**

```
/usr/local/bin/python:
    /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Python (compatibility version 2.7.0, current version 2.7.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`python` was point to the wrong version

Fixed by running `hash -d python`